# Maximize does not maximize to full screen in 3 monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde

My setup has three monitors. The left and right monitors are Full HD, and the middle monitor is 2560x1440.

On middle screen, maximizing any application does not fill the entire screen. The width is correct but the height seems to be 1080 (I guess it takes the height of the wrong screen). Also when I open the KDE menu, it appears far above the button.

[image: Example with Firefox maximized and KDE menu open]

I can resize each window manually to fill the entire screen. Also the bottom panel is correctly positioned.

How can I help KDE/X11 seeing the correct dimensions?

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10, KDE Plasma 5.17.3, KDE FrameWorks 5.64.0, Qt 5.12.4, DisplayLink 5.2

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by moving one of my monitors in System Settings => Display Configuration. The issue occurred for me because my left monitor is slightly above my center monitor, and in Display Configuration my left monitor "overlapped" my center monitor. This caused my center monitor to act like the bottom of my left monitor was also the bottom of my center monitor. It resulted in exactly the same symptoms as the image in the OP.

This solution was to leave a very small gap between the left and center monitor in the Display Configuration page. Without this gap my center monitor always behaved as if the center and left were overlapping

Comment: Thank you, I've been plagued by the same problem.  Your solution fixed it for me.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the docking station. Switched it off and on and screen was correctly recognized.